# Integral over Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A : [0,T] \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}, t \mapsto A(t)$ be smooth with the property that

$$ \int_{0}^T A(t) dt $$ is invertible.

Does it then follow that the matrix

$$ \int_{0}^T A(t) \otimes A(t) dt $$

is also invertible? Here $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $\Delta $ is a diagonal matrix with entries $(\lambda _1,\ldots ,\lambda _n)$, $\Delta \otimes \Delta $ is diagonal with entries $(\lambda _{i}\lambda _j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$.  Now take two functions $a(t)$, $b(t)$ such that $\int_0^Ta(t)dt>0$, $\int_0^Tb(t)dt>0$ but $\int_0^Ta(t)b(t)dt<0$ (for instance, with $T=2$, take $a(t)=0$ in $[0,1]$,  $a(t)=t-1$ in $[1,2]$; $b(t)=2( 1-t)$ in $[0,1]$, $b(t)= (1-t)$ in $[1,2]$). The matrix $A(t)=\pmatrix {a(t) &0\\0&b(t)}$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: thanks. i edited the question. If i am only interested in invertibility, would you feel that that would be true then?

Comment: No, the same example works -- just arrange so that $\int_0^Ta(t)b(t)dt=0$ instead of $<0$, that's easy.